# For all sets $A$, $B$ and $C$, if $A=B\cup C$ then $A-B=C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or disprove the statement

> For all sets $A$, $B$ and $C$, if $A=B\cup C$ then $A-B=C$

I'm not too sure if it's true or not. Please explain your thinking and show your work.

Thank you!

Comment: What work have you done on this already?

Comment: Hint: try with a very small set (not *too* small).

Comment: If you show us what you have tried then we might be able to see where you are having difficulty.

Comment: ... now can our overeager answerers restrain themselves?

Comment: Hint2: Try with an element that is in the intersection of B and C

Comment: Please show your work and explain your thinking.

Comment: I did a venn diagram to see if it was true or false and it seems like its true.

Comment: @Jam: A Venn diagram is a good start. Did the two circles intersect? What does $A-B$ look like?

Comment: C. But that means that A=BUC is all of B and C and A is empty. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jam: I suppose you should say what $A$, $B$, and $C$ are in the Venn diagram? Try setting $B$ and $C$ to be the circles, $A$ the union of the two (with intersection). I think you have the right idea, you just need to think about definitions of union and subtracting sets from one another.

Comment: For what it's worth, the difference of two sets can be typeset using "A \setminus B" : $A \setminus B$.  I know a lot of people use the regular minus sign for this purpose, but I can't think of a good reason not to use \setminus.  Using a minus sign, one might think (in some problems, not this one) a "Minkowski difference" is intended, but with \setminus, there is probably no possible confusion.  I'm telling you in case you don't know about \setminus.  If you really like using a minus sign I doubt I'll change your mind.

Answer (score 3):

What do you think of

$$B:=\{1\}\;,\;\;C:=\{1,2\}\;,\;\;A:=\{1,2\}\;\;?$$

Comment: I was thinking to $A=B=C=\{0\}$.

Comment: Too fat a number for my taste...

Comment: What about $A=B=C=\{|\}$, then?

Comment: Too thin...tsk,tsk,tsk. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would try to *construct* a proof or counterexample: by translating to the level of elements, and using the laws of logic to simplify.

First, by the one-point rule, we can simplify the original statement:
\begin{align}
& \langle \forall A,B,C : A = B \cup C : A \setminus B = C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"one-point rule for $\;A\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall B,C :: (B \cup C) \setminus B = C \rangle \\
\end{align}

Now, we can go to the element-level and simplify, as follows:
\begin{align}
& (B \cup C) \setminus B = C \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"set extensionality; definitions of $\;\setminus\;$ and $\;\cup\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: (x \in B \lor x \in C) \land x \not\in B \;\equiv\; x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: assume right side of $\;\land\;$ in left side"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: (\text{false} \lor x \in C) \land x \not\in B \;\equiv\; x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in C \land x \not\in B \;\equiv\; x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: $\;P \land Q \equiv P\;$ and $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$ are different ways to write $\;P \Rightarrow Q\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \not\in C \lor x \not\in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: DeMorgan -- to go back the set level"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \lnot (x \in C \land x \in B) \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definitions of $\;\cap\;$ and $\;\emptyset\;$"} \\
& C \cap B = \emptyset \\
\end{align}

So, in other words, the original statement is only true iff $\;B\;$ and $\;C\;$ have no elements in common.  Therefore a counterexample would be $\;B = \{1,2,4,8\}\;$ and $\;C = \{1,3,9,27\}\;$ (from which $\;A\;$ of course follows).

Answer (score 0):

Use Venn diagram to disprove the statement.

The following Venn diagram shows the region of $A-B$:

[image]